# equality between symmetric differences

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to show this property of the symmetric difference.
I want to show in which case this equality holds:

$$
\mathbb{P}(A\Delta C) = \mathbb{P}(A\Delta B)+\mathbb{P}(B\Delta C)
$$

What I know is that $$
\mathbb{P}(A\Delta C)\leq \mathbb{P}(A\Delta B)+\mathbb{P}(B\Delta C)
$$ always holds and the $\subseteq$ comes from the monotonicity.

To show the equality i was thinking about using "$[(A \bigtriangleup B) \bigcup (B \bigtriangleup C)] \setminus (A \bigtriangleup C) = (A \bigtriangleup B) \bigcap (B \bigtriangleup C)$" but I even have to show the latter and i don't know how to do it.

Comment: Will showing that $\mathbb P((A\Delta B)\cap (B\Delta C))=0$ is equivalent to the probability statement you have, be enough? Or are you looking for sth more?

Comment: Yes, but firstly I'd like to prove $[(A \bigtriangleup B) \bigcup (B \bigtriangleup C)] \setminus (A \bigtriangleup C) = (A \bigtriangleup B) \bigcap (B \bigtriangleup C)$ and i don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Oh, that follows fairly simply using the associativity of symmetric difference. Note that for any sets $X$ and $Y$, $(X\cup Y)\setminus (X\Delta Y)=X\cap Y$. Putting $X=A\Delta B$ and $Y=B\Delta C$, we have $X\Delta Y=(A\Delta B)\Delta (B\Delta C)=(A\Delta(B\Delta B))\Delta C=(A\Delta\varnothing)\Delta C=A\Delta C$ and the result follows.

Comment: Ok but this is not showing me that the LHS is equal to the RHS. In this case you're just re-writing XΔY as AΔC. Am I wrong?

Comment: I showed that $X\Delta Y=A\Delta C$. Then $[(A \Delta B) \cup (B \Delta C)] \setminus (A \Delta C)=(X\cup Y)\setminus (X\Delta Y)=X\cap Y=(A \Delta B)\cup (B \Delta C)$ which is what you wanted.

Comment: *the last term is $(A \Delta B)\cap (B \Delta C)$, it's a typo in the above comment. Sorry about that.

Comment: Got that. Thank you!

Comment: @HackR Maybe you could write your comment into an answer, that I will certainly upvote.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Thank you for the advice! I wrote an answer using just basic set theoretic arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X=\mathbf{1}_A$, $Y=\mathbf{1}_B$ and $Z=\mathbf{1}_C$. Since for sets $E$ and $F$, the indicator function of $E\Delta F$ is $\left\lvert \mathbb{1}_E-\mathbb{1}_F\right\rvert$, the equality $$\tag{*}\mathbb{P}(A\Delta C) = \mathbb{P}(A\Delta B)+\mathbb{P}(B\Delta C)$$ is equivalent to
$$
\mathbb E\left\lvert X-Z\right\rvert=\mathbb E\left\lvert X-Y\right\rvert+\mathbb E\left\lvert Y-Z\right\rvert
$$
and the triangle inequality is an equality if and only if
$$
\mathbb E\left[\left(X-Y\right)\left(Y-Z\right)\right]=0.
$$
Splitting this expectation as
$$ 
\mathbb E\left[\left(X-Y\right)\left(Y-Z\right)Y\right]+\mathbb E\left[\left(X-Y\right)\left(Y-Z\right)(1-Y)\right]
$$
we can see that (*) holds if and only if
$$
\mathbb P\left(A\cap B^c\cap C\right)= \mathbb P\left(A^c\cap B\cap C^c\right)=0,
$$
or equivalently, as found by HackR,
$\mathbb P((A\Delta B)\cap (B\Delta C))=0$

Answer (score 2):

For brevity, we write $X=A\Delta B$ and $Y=B\Delta C$. Then we note that $$X\Delta Y=(A\Delta B)\Delta(B\Delta C)=A\Delta(B\Delta B)\Delta C=(A\Delta \varnothing)\Delta C=A\Delta C$$

where we used the associative property of symmetric difference multiple times.

We also have $$X\Delta Y=(X\cap Y^c)\cup(X^c\cap Y)$$

Now, for later use, we note down the following $$X=(X\cap Y^c)\cup(X\cap Y)$$ $$Y=(Y\cap X^c)\cup(X\cap Y)$$

All the three set unions above are disjoint (check it!).

Then, we have

$$\mathbb{P}(A\Delta C) = \mathbb{P}(A\Delta B)+\mathbb{P}(B\Delta C)\iff \mathbb P(X\Delta Y)=\mathbb P(X)+\mathbb P(Y)$$

Plugging in the above set equalities, we get

$$\mathbb P(X\cap Y^c)+\mathbb P(X^c\cap Y)=\mathbb P(X\cap Y^c)+\mathbb P(Y\cap X^c)+2\mathbb P(X\cap Y)$$

or equivalently $$\mathbb P(X\cap Y)=0$$

Plugging back the values for $X$ and $Y$, we are left with

$$\mathbb{P}(A\Delta C) = \mathbb{P}(A\Delta B)+\mathbb{P}(B\Delta C)\iff \mathbb P((A\Delta B)\cap (B\Delta C))=0$$

---

For the sake of completion, I do want to mention that the set equality mentioned in the question is also true.

For any two sets $M$ and $N$, it is true that $$(M\cup N)\setminus (M\Delta N)=M\cap N$$

Plugging in $M=X,\ N=Y$ and the facts from the previous part of the answer, we get

$$[(A \Delta B) \cup (B \Delta C)] \setminus (A \Delta C)=(A \Delta B)\cap (B \Delta C)$$